# How to search especial characters in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search, special-characters

I was confused when i wanted to search `*` mark in my file. I know how to use star mark`(*)` for search but I don't know how to search star mark in the file.

Ex: in my file have this content

```
   /*some text*/
    .. other text ..
```

how can I search star mark line ?

*I don't think this is a stupid question. Anyway this is really a question for me.*

Comment: Ctrl-F in the file, input just star sign and "Find" button. Is it the thing you need?

Comment: you right. but how about the package search? not in the single file.

Comment: Select the package -> Click Search -> Java.... In "Search String" input "\*", in Scope panel choose "Selected resources"

Answer (score 1):

When using the advanced search dialog in Eclipse, you can escape special characters by using the `"\"` character.
So for example if you are looking for `"*"` literally, then you need to enter `"\*"` in the search text box.

https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fref%2Frsearch.html